# Browser windows is going out of screen

Tags: linux, browser

After an update in Kali Linux, the browser window is some kind of enlarged I cant see the maximize, minimize or close button, not even the open tabs. I have updated the system with `apt update && apt full-upgrade` and then I noticed there was a kernel update the update was completed successfully and then I restarted the system. when I opened the browser this weird behavior happened. For the first time if we opened the browser there is no issue, if we minimize and then maximize the issue is occurring
the kernel was updated from 5.10 to 5.14 stable

[this is how it looks before minimizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HHUl.png)

[this what it looks after minimizing and then maximizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44jcN.png)

this problem is with both browser chrome and Microsoft edge.

I am using kali Linux 2021.3(Xfce)

installed on an HDD

Please help me if anyone know the solution

regards,

Adithyan

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does pressing `F11` fix your problem?

Comment: by pressing f11 it will go in full screen , no its not the problem . https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HHUl.png you can see this is before and  https://i.stack.imgur.com/44jcN.png  is after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new kernal update solved the issue.